# Subir archivos .php a host

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, host

Hice un sistema basico y estoy intentando subirlo al host, lo que pasa es que al subirlo y crear la base de datos en mysql que brinda el servicio, no me manda el registro al mismo.

Ya modifique el archivo de conexion y de configuracion por los datos que me brinda el servidor, Pero creo que hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

El host es gratuito, es de la pagina de Tonohost.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Chequea que la base de datos en el hosting se llame igual (phplogin) de otro modo debes usar el nombre de base de datos que te proporciona el hosting cuando la creaste (muchas veces tiene un prefijo), ademas del usuario/password proporcionado para dicha BD.

Comment: te recomiendo dos cosas 1 agrega codigo 2 no coloques nombre de servidores y usarios de cualquier tipo en un sitio donde puede entrar cualquier persona

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por sus consejos